# Handover data as tuples to function in abaqus python code

Tags: python, abaqus

I would like to hand over some tuples to a function. 
the values x1, x2, y1, y2 are stored in an array. I tried to handover an array, but this does not do the jobs.

```
x = [0,1,2]
y = [11,12,13]    

faces = f.findAt(((x[1], y[1], 0.0), ), ((x[2], y[2],
    0.0), ), (([x3], [y3], 0.0), ))
```

I try to ask the question another way:

For the function f.findAt I would like to handover the values as follows:

faces = f.findAt(((x1, y1, 0.0), ), ((x2, y2,
        0.0), ), ((x3, y3, 0.0), )+ .....)

so the data is ((x1, y1,0.0),)   ...        ((x_n, y_n, 0.0,))

So far x1, y1 etc are stored in a list.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the error message or undesired behavior? Your example has a couple of problems - mainly with `[x3]` and `[y3]`. I'm not sure if that's just a typo and you meant `x[3]` and `y[3]` (which would also be a problem because of the sizes of x and y), or if this is your actual code. Including the error will help us understand the problem much better.

Comment: also to add to brandy's comment x[3] would be out of bounds for the defined list. In python lists start with index 0. In this case it would be x[0], x[1], x[2]

Answer (score 1):

Just do

```py
foo([tuple((1,2)), tuple((4,5)), tuple((5,6))])
```